# How do I optimize query to find random values for large tables

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
class ImageRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllNewestByVotes()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p FROM GabrielUploadBundle:Image p WHERE p.upvotes > 50 ORDER BY p.createdAt ASC')
        ->getResult();
    }
}
```

I Only need 10 to 20 random pictures from  the GabrielUploadBundle:Image where upvotes are more than 50, at the moment its only sorted by date (createdAt).
I know this could be solved with RAND() but its not recommended for large tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in these four steps:

- select IDs of all records with up votes more than 50
- shuffle the array
- slice the array to the size you need
- use the IDs you get in new select with IN clause

Comment: wouldn't that require me to pass all results as parameter to the shuffle(<array>) function and slow down the server, since thousands of results would have to be randomized?

Comment: I have an idea. Instead of shuffling the array, generate new array with random values from 0 to the size of the first array and use generated values as keys to the first array elements.